# Playing videos in UITableViewCell (Vine) - performance issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, video, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation (AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer) in order to play video within UITableviewCell. However,when I scroll the table view, the scrolling is not smooth.Videos that are viewable on the screen while scrolling start playing automaticaly.When they are scrolled out they stop playing. So how to play these videos corectly so that it doesn't affect the scrolling smoothness?

Comment: Is your video playing while you're scrolling? Are you allowing multiple videos to play simultaneously?

Comment: One or two videos play at all times. Yes, while scrolling. Videos start as soon as they become visible and stop when they exit the screen.

Comment: Not cool closing my question. What's unclear in it? Stackoverflow is not what it used to be.

Comment: @AlexTau I am also facing the same issue? Were you able to fix it?